# How to display message at ListBox when binding source?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I am new programmer for UWP app.

I tried to show a list of string messages in my UWP app. 
I call `ShowReceiveMessage` and use `Listbox` with a binding to a `CollectionViewSource` with an `ObservableCollection<string>` as source to display the messages.
I faced three issues:

1. It sometimes crashes when sending message, but I don't find the reason:

   > An unhandled win32 exception occurred in [6284 or 24324 or 9428] Wcons.exe
2. Messages are duplicated when clicking the button twice.
3. The `ListBox` scrolls to the end after each new message.

Below is my code:

#### MainPage.xaml.cs

```cs
private ObservableCollection<string> m_OutputList = new ObservableCollection<string>();

private async void ShowReceiveMessage(string szMsg)
{
   await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
   {
       m_OutputList.Add(szMsg);
   });
}

public MainPage()
{
   this.InitializeComponent();
   ResultListSource.Source = m_OutputList;
}
```

#### MainPage.xaml

```xml
<Page.Resources>
   <CollectionViewSource x:Name="ResultListSource"/>
</Page.Resources>    

<ListBox x:Name="lstResult" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ResultListSource}}" />
```

Comment: I tested your code and every time called the ShowReceiveMessage method, the ListBox displayed well. It didn't crash and show duplicate messages. Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: Could you also please show the code and XAML for your `Button` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed 2nd/3rd question, but can't find root cause for 1st question.
It would stop at code line:  m_OutputList.Add(szMsg) and show Error message is "An unhandled exception for type 'System.AccessViolatonException'" occurred in System.ObjectModel.dll. Attempted
to read or write protected memory. This is often and indication that other memory is corrupt.

below code is for button click

```
private void btnWcosIAPClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Run(async () => 
    {
      await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
      {
          m_OutputList.Clear();
          ResultListSource.Source = m_OutputList;
          btnWcosIAP.IsEnabled = lstResult.IsEnabled = false;
      });

      int iRes = BurningData_Run();

      await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
      {
          btnWcosIAP.IsEnabled = lstResult.IsEnabled = true;
          ResultListSource.Source = null;
      });
    });
}            

private int BurningData_Run()
{
 m_DATA.RecvMsgCallback += ShowIAPReceiveMessage;
..
 m_DATA.RecvMsgCallback -= ShowIAPReceiveMessage;
}
```

m_DATA is my custome class for do my functon

Comment: When you called the ShowReceiveMessage method? And can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?